# Error when trying to view properties in Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2005, database, ssms

I am having trouble with sql manager after install SQL 2005 SP3,

Can any shed any light on this one.

Thanks

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Cannot show requested dialog.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Cannot show requested dialog. (SqlMgmt)

---

Method not found: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Edition Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Information.get_EngineEdition()'. (SqlManagerUI)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Answer (score 1):

This might have something that can resolve the issue: http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/7/1/5718A94A-3931-457B-8567-AA0995E34870/ReleaseNotesSQL2005SP3.htm

Answer (score 1):

If it was a databases's properties you were trying to look at, check the owner of the database you are trying to look at. It might be orphaned - you can use

```
EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa'
```

and see if that helps
(doesn't have to be sa - whatever the appropriate account is)

Answer (score 0):

There could be some missing SQL Server SMO assembly files. To solve this, just follow this procedure:

1. Look for an installation which works fine
2. Copy all files from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\SDK\Assemblies` folder and paste it in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\SDK\Assemblies` of the machine with the corrupted installation.
3. Don't overwrite any file. Just copy the missing files

Comment: There was a massive difference in the files in the two locations, and i copied them over, but it didn't fix it. I'm not sure what service pack the files came from however.

Comment: Can you try to re-apply the SP?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you applied the service pack to a different instance than the one to which you are attempting to connect?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have enough privileges to see that dialog, SSME will throw that error. Check your users privileges.